# Can I create class-based React Styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I just started looking into using Styled Components for a JavaScript React web application, and I'm wondering if it's possible to use class-based styled components. For example:

Functional (works):

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Header = styled.header`
    color: blue;
`;

export default Header;

.
.
.

(in another file)
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Header>
          This is my header.
        </Header>
    );
  }
}
```

Class-based (I would be interested if something like this could be done--does not work...color is not applied to my header):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                Hi there. Test.
            </header>
    )};
}

export default styled(Header)`
  color: blue;
`;

.
.
.

(in another file)
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        </Header>
    );
  }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, you just need to pass the className prop to the JSX element you wish to have the styled-component class, and actually you can pass any other props, since styled-components pass all the props down to its wrapped component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

    class Header extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <header className={this.props.className}>
                    Hi there here is another prop {this.props.anotherProp}
                </header>
        )};
    }

    export const StyledHeader styled(Header)`
      color: blue;
    `;

   // you can pass other props down to Header
   <StyledHeader
     anotherProp='testing!!'/>
```

you can see examples of this pattern in their [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components). Hope it helps!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I read that portion of the docs you linked, but I was thrown off, since it is written in the functional form (I'm still a bit new to React). Would [this portion](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#caveat) of the docs be applicable (the second example...the one with `const StyledA = styled(A)\`\``)? I did test this, though, and it seems to work as I was hoping it would :)

Comment: Yes, you can see they are using class components there, passing the className prop. On the other hand, I haven't used the component interpolation (I surely will), but It seams to work as long as you target a styled-component and not a React component.